What is the translation of point man in French?
A point man is defined as follows:

North American (especially in a political context), a person at the forefront of an activity or endeavor.
"Olson was the defense department's point man when the government recently changed pension legislation".

What is the translation of point man in French?
Google Translate suggests:

Olson était l'homme clé du ministère de la Défense lorsque le gouvernement a récemment modifié la législation sur les retraites.

But l'homme clé means the key man, which isn't necessarily the point man: the point man is the person who is at the forefront, which doesn't always mean the most important.

Comments have been moved to chat; do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion will be removed.

@FrançoisJurain I don't get the "Dictionary-lookup" vote to close. How can I do the dictionary-lookup if I don't know the translation? Also, fr.Wkt Déf. 8 is for military use, as mentioned in https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pointe and in this comment. Lastly, it is missing the other options mentioned in the answers below (visage, figure de proue, etc.)

@FrançoisJurain the question is already clear that it doesn't focus on military use cases.

@FrançoisJurain French is my native language and I've never heard "l'homme à la pointe". I barely see any occurrences of it on Google.

@FrançoisJurain I provided one: l'homme clé

You're right; I'm being unfair. This belongs on Meta I think; feel free to go there first.

@FrançoisJurain Thanks, I'll ask on meta if this gets closed.

Frank, a point man is not always the face of the company. A point man can be the "go to person" for information purposes. I don't see why you chose visage, really.

@Lambie thanks that's why I wrote it's an option

But if visage de l'entreprise is face of the company, how can point man be that??

Olson était la figure de proue du ministère de la Défense.

Définition : Membre emblématique d’un groupe, celui qui est le plus en vue, chef
de file d’un mouvement, d’un courant de pensée.
Exemple : "Il est une figure de proue du parti, 
mais ses hautes fonctions l’obligent à une certaine réserve."


Source wikipedia
"Figure de proue"  is usually translated by "figurehead" or "leading figure".

leading figure is not a point man.

Merriam Webster:
Merriam Webster: 2: one who is in the forefront especially : a principal spokesman or advocate
[for example] the point man for the President's economic policy –
point man [d'une entreprise ou organization politique, etc.]
principal porte-parole
"A la suite des déclarations faites par le principal porte-parole du président en première page du" (Commission Européenne 2007 "Texte de la Commission Européenne")
principaux porte-parole [point men]
"Aux termes des modifications apportées à l'article 74, un petit syndicat local pouvait encore recourir à des agents spécialisés extérieurs à la province et associés à un réseau national ou international dans le cadre du comité de négociation et en faire ses principaux porte-parole, mais une personne résidant dans la province devait être dotée du pouvoir requis afin de faciliter la conduite de la négociation, notamment la conclusion d'une convention collective." (Collectif 1985 "Rapport de l'OIT")
cordial.fr
Je pense qu'on peut oublier le mot pointe en français. En anglais, le terme n'est plus militaire. Un porte-parole occupe le devant de la "scène".
